# Mongo DB Authentication 3.0.4

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I am having an issue with mongo db 3.0.4 that randomly started happening today. The authentication stopped working randomly without any user action on our part. Our setup is easy. One application, one database. I take the application out of the equation and I still get the same result. Here are the steps I am taking. Reinstalled mongo and pointed the logpath and dbpath to a new folder to start from scratch.

Create the config file.

```
logpath=c:\data\logs\mongod.log
dbpath=c:\data\db
```

Log in to mongo shell and run this command.

```
db.createUser({user: "admin",pwd: "admin", roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }]})
```

Add the auth=true in the config file.

```
auth=true
```

Restart the mongodb service.

Start up mongo shell with

```
mongo -u admin -p admin --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Then I get the Error 18 Authentication failed.

I am really lost for words. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think user doesn't have efficient privileges. try with this role.

```
use admin
{user:"admin",pwd:"admin",roles:["root"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before create the user, you need to change the db and create it in admin db.

1. Disable auth
2. Enter to mongo shell
3. Change db to admin ('use admin')
4. now create the user.
5. Enable the auth again (with auth or mongodb-keyfile)
6. Enter mongo shell with:

   ```
   mongo -u admin -p admin --authenticationDatabase admin
   ```